# Как обойти отсутствие множественного наследования на Java(для конкретной задачи)?

Tags: java

Существует классы студент и работник, которые наследуют от человека. Но также необходим класс работающий студент(в котором должен содержаться функционал и работника и студента). Каким образом лучше это реализовать в данной ситуации? С использованием интерфейсов, абстрактных классов, суперпозиции? 
В дальнейшем будет решаться задача сортировки студентов и работающих студентов,внесенных в один список, по их баллу.

```
public class Human {

String name;

Human(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}

class Student extends Human {
int grade;

Student(String name, int grade) {
    super(name);
    this.grade = grade;
}
}

class Worker extends Human {
int salary;

Worker(String name, int salary) {
    super(name);
    this.salary = salary;
}

class WorkingStudent {
    // TODO
}
}
```

Comment: У вас будут в классы добавляться ещё поля?

Comment: Посмотрите реализацию паттерна Стратегия.

Comment: @Dred нет, скорее всего, но как это может повлиять?

Comment: @Alex, это значит, что вы можете сделать всё в рамках 1 класса. Если, конечно же, у вас эти наследования не сделаны в академических целях

Comment: @Dred как раз в академических

Comment: @Alex В таком случае, тут вам самостоятельно надо решать. Если была бы проблема с реализацией, вам бы помогли, а так, вы просите ее придумать. По факту, я вижу 2 варианта, более профессионалы, наверное, увидят куда больше

Comment: @Dred Хорошо, спасибо. Я тоже вижу два способа, просто хотелось именно узнать, какой вариант тут лучше, с точки зрения гораздо более опытных людей.

Comment: я одного не понял: работающий студент - это нелюдь чтоли? наследуйте его от человека, а уже от него всех работающих студентов. ну а неработающих, соответсвенно, просто от человека. в чем вопрос то?

Answer (score 1):

В Java есть множественное наследование - но для интерфейсов. Используйте их. Потому что потом у Вас появится еще кто-то кроме студентов и работников - директор, например. Это самый гибкий способ - меньше зависимостей в коде. А значит, любые изменения не будут затрагивать другие классы (при условии что конструкторы тоже не будут зависеть от реализации конкретной).